# Facebook Unity SDK v6.2.2 not retrieving info

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, unity-game-engine, sdk

**Using**

- Unity 4.6.8 patch 2
- Facebook Unity SDK v6.2.2

**Problem**

Facebook's Unity SDK is not retrieving the info correctly.

I have the code below,

```
FB.Login("email,publish_actions,user_friends”,Callback);
FB.API ("me?fields=id,name,friends.limit(100).fields(first_name,id)", 
Facebook.HttpMethod.GET, (_result)=>{});
```

And with it, I get the number of friends in the summary, but not the name and ID. Is this because the Unity SDK ver 6.2.2 is not using GraphAPI ver2.4? How can I retrieve the friends name and ID?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can only get those friends which are also using your app (since Graph API 2.0!), so if none of your friends are actually using your app, then the result is perfectly fine.

See

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog#v2_0

Comment: Thanks for the reply. We've used two test accounts, thus thought it'd be ok... but I guess not...